# Won their race in this circle

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sen. Jim Brewster, a McKeesport Democrat who has represented the 45th District for the last decade, defeated Republican Nicole Ziccarelli by 69 votes in the Nov. 3 contest, but didn’t get to take the oath of office on the Senate floor with the 24 others who won their races in ***this cycle***.

[Reference](https://www.post-gazette.com/news/politics-state/2021/01/05/Pa-Senate-refuses-to-seat-McKeesport-s-Brewster-in-contentious-swearing-in-ceremony/stories/202101050125)

---

I'd like to know what ***this cycle*** means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Politicians are elected to serve a specific number of years in office, which is called their **term**.

The process of campaigning/electioneering prior to the vote, and the vote itself, is called the **election cycle**. Like other cycles, it is a loop: campaign, election, swearing-in, legislating, campaigning again. In some legislative bodies, all of the politicians have their terms expire at the same time. In others, such as the United States Senate, the term lengths are all the same (six years) but they are offset so only one-third are up for election each cycle (every two years).

With all this in mind, "the 24 others who won their races in this cycle" means "the other politicians who were voted in to office this election year."